# Sort a foreach loop based on variable

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, variables, foreach

I have a frontend table form (using Advanced Custom Fields plugin for WordPress) for users to track the number of days each week that they ride their bike to work. Each person has their own row and enters their number for each week. Then I loop through to add up the total number entered for each row and list each person's name along with their total.

How can I sort this so that the names are listed in order by the highest total ($overalltotal)? Here is my code, which correctly lists the names along with their totals, but it is unsorted:

```
 $rows = get_sub_field('ride_tracker');

 foreach( $rows as $row )
    {

    $overalltotal = intval($row['week_1'] + $row['week_2'] + $row['week_3'] + $row['week_4']);

    echo $row['name'] . ' : ' . $overalltotal . '<br />' ;

    }
```

I've read about array_multisort and usort, but I can't figure out how to get these to work with a variable that's calculated during the loop.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you try with: `$rows = sort($rows);` before the foreach ?

Comment: I just tried it. And it gave me this: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Ok, now I see. $rows is an array, if you want to order it by keys, just ` $rows = get_sub_field('ride_tracker');` and after `ksort($rows);`

Comment: I tried ksort($rows) where you indicated, but it had no effect. I need to sort by the variable $overalltotal, which is calculated inside the foreach loop, so it seems the sorting code would have to come after that, no?

Comment: You can not do the calculation _and_ the sorting both in one and the same loop – that should be obvious, if you think about it: You can not sort values while not all of them have even been calculated yet. Put the names and the overall totals into an array, sort that array – and then use a second loop to output the data.

Comment: That makes sense. Though I don't know how to put it into an array? I know the basic array format is: $fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana"); But I don't know how to translate my code into an array.

Comment: I opted to use jquery to sort the final list instead. It's probably not the best way, but it was simpler for me to implement. (I used this code: http://jsfiddle.net/2uMjv/7) But I'll leave the question open in case someone wants to answer with a better way.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

ACF is an awesome plugin. I use it for everything.

I see you are using sub_fields so I assume you are using a repeater.

ACF uses this format `array_multisort( $column_id, SORT_ASC, $repeater );`

This page may help you out a lot, shows how to sort fields in ACF.

> http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/how-to-sorting-a-repeater-field/